# PyYaml parses '9:00' as int

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I have a file with the following data:

```
classes:
  - 9:00
  - 10:20
  - 12:10
```

(and so on up to 21:00)

I use python3 and yaml module to parse it. Precisely, the source is `config = yaml.load (open (filename, 'r'))`. But then, when I `print` `config`, I get the following output for this part of data:

```
'classes': [540, 630, 730, 820, 910, 1000, 1090, 1180],
```

The values in the list are ints.

While previously, when I used python2 (and `BaseLoader` for YAML), I got the values as strings, and I use them as such. `BaseLoader` is now not acceptable since I want to read unicode strings from file, and it gives me byte-strings.

So, first, why pyyaml does parse my data as ints?

And, second, how do I prevent pyyaml from doing this? Is it possible to do that **without changing data file** (e.g. without adding `!!str`)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The documentation of YAML is a bit difficult to "parse" so I can imagine you missed this [little bit of info](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2791372) about colons:

> Normally, YAML insists the “:” mapping value indicator be separated from the value by white space. A benefit of this restriction is that the “:” character can be used inside plain scalars, as long as it is not followed by white space. This allows for unquoted URLs and timestamps. It is also a potential source for confusion as “a:1” is a plain scalar and not a key: value pair.

And what you have there in your input is a [sexagesimal](http://yaml.org/spec/spec.html#id2561981) and your `9:00` is considered to be similar to 9 minutes and 0 seconds, equalling a total of 540 seconds.

Unfortunately this doesn't get constructed as some special Sexagesimal instance that can be used for calculations as if it were an integer but can be printed in its original form. Therefore, if you want to use this as a string internally you have to single quote them:

```
classes:
  - '9:00'
  - '10:20'
  - '12:10'
```

which is what you would get if you dump `{'classes': ['9:00', '10:20', '12:10']}` (and note that the unambiguous `classes` doesn't get any quotes).

That the `BaseLoader` gives you strings is not surprising. The `BaseConstructor` that is used by the `BaseLoader` handles **any** scalar as string, including integers, booleans and "your" sexagesimals:

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml

yaml_str = """\
classes:
  - 12345
  - 10:20
  - abc
  - True
"""

data = yaml.load(yaml_str, Loader=yaml.BaseLoader)
print(data)
data = yaml.load(yaml_str, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)
```

gives:

```
{u'classes': [u'12345', u'10:20', u'abc', u'True']}
{'classes': [12345, 620, 'abc', True]}
```

---

If you really don't want to use quotes, then you have to "reset" the implicit resolver for scalars that start with numbers:

```
import ruamel.yaml as yaml
from ruamel.yaml.resolver import Resolver
import re

yaml_str = """\
classes:
  - 9:00
  - 10:20
  - 12:10
"""

for ch in list(u'-+0123456789'):
    del Resolver.yaml_implicit_resolvers[ch]
Resolver.add_implicit_resolver(
    u'tag:yaml.org,2002:int',
    re.compile(u'''^(?:[-+]?0b[0-1_]+
    |[-+]?0o?[0-7_]+
    |[-+]?(?:0|[1-9][0-9_]*)
    |[-+]?0x[0-9a-fA-F_]+)$''', re.X),  # <- copy from resolver.py without sexagesimal support
    list(u'-+0123456789'))

data = yaml.load(yaml_str, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)
print(data)
```

gives you:

```
{'classes': ['9:00', '10:20', '12:10']}
```

Answer (score -6):

You should probably check the [documentation of YAML](http://www.yaml.org/)

The colon are for mapping values.

I presume you want a string and not an integer, so you should double quote your strings.

Comment: This link is already marked visited in my browser :) I should have read it more carefully. Though, now while quickly scanning yaml spec, I did not find my specific case. Anyway, thank you for solution.