# What does 09:00 mean in YAML?

Tags: yaml, pyyaml

What does `09:00` mean in YAML? Does it have an official definition?

I can't see [anything about this syntax in the tags section of the spec](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2761292). Given the following YAML:

```
- 09:00
- 10:00
```

PyYAML only interprets the first one as a string

```py
 >>> import yaml
 >>> yaml.load("- 09:00\n- 10:00")
 ['09:00', 600]
```

Whereas [YAMLlint](http://www.yamllint.com/) converts both to what looks like seconds:

```
--- 
- 32400
- 36000
```

What should it be? Is this well defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to the 1.2 version of the specification, but PyYAML is only 1.1 compliant. In the 1.1 spec there is reference to [sexagesimals](http://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#id858734) and the code for that is what recognises the `09:00` as an integer.

My answer [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31007425/1307905) gives an example on how to tweak my [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) (derived from PyYAML) to not recognise the sexagesimals as integers, but as strings. You should be able to apply that trick to PyYAML itself as well.

Starting with ruamel.yaml 0.11 its RoundTripLoader will default to not support sexagesimals in documents not explicitly marked `%YAML 1.1`.